# How to counting total number of rows greater than zero in gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have grid view in asp.net page using SQLDataSource.
I want display total number of rows greater than zero in label.Text.
(my column is column of price and I want count rows that price is greater than zero
how can i do that
i try this code for total number of rows:
**int totalRows = e.AffectedRows;** 
thanks

Comment: `lblCount.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count > 0 ? GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString() : "---"`;

Comment: my column is column of price and I want count rows that price is greater than zero

Comment: my column is column of price and I want count rows that price is greater than zero

Comment: salam khoshalam iraniha hameja hastand

Comment: For such issues you should use the source table which is stored in `DataSource` of the `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use linq for comparing the values with price > 0

for eg:-

```
var count = objVar.Where(x=>x.price > 0).count();
```

Comment: thanks  .no I want counting total number of rows greater than zero

Comment: No it's LINQ query in c#. Use this query to get the total no. of rows int the function where you want the count

Comment: thanks for reply please help me it is very important for me to solve it

Comment: give me the data object definition

Comment: i have gridview with 5 columns 1-id 2-products 3- price 4- date -5 time

Comment: Create a list or array and then use the LINQ query to get the records count

Answer (score 0):

In order to read directly from cells in the `GridView`, I used a method named `GetPrice()` which returns a list of all prices in a specific column.

Note: You should specify which column is related to `Price` in the `GridView`, so the index(Zero-Based) of `Price` column must be set in the `PriceColumnIndex` constant variable.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<double> lstPrice = GetPrice();
    double dblPriceSum = lstPrice.Where(p => p > 0).Sum();

    lblCount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0  Rls}", dblPriceSum);
}

private List<double> GetPrice()
{
    const int PriceColumnIndex = 0;

    List<double> resList = new List<double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string strPrice = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[PriceColumnIndex].Text;
        double dblPrice;
        bool blIsParsable = double.TryParse(strPrice, out dblPrice);

        if (blIsParsable)
            resList.Add(dblPrice);
    }

    return resList;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: what namespace should be add for recognize List<double> ?

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic;` for List collection, and `using System.Linq;` for LINQ statement.

Comment: no ,no I dont want sum of data in column of price but i want count of rows of column of price this code is sum of  price in all rows? i want count of rows that price is greater than zero

Comment: Use `Count` method instead of `Sum` method in `double dblPriceSum = lstPrice.Where(p => p > 0).Sum();`

Comment: salam thanks it work successfully (count instead sum) but this code is count of rows of every page of gridview but I want count rows of all page of grid view  thanks

Comment: salam thanks it work successfully (count instead sum) but this code is count of rows of every page of gridview but I want count rows of all page of grid view thanks

Comment: You can trick to getting the wanted result. Add `GridView1.AllowPaging = false;` just at the beginning of the `Page_Load` event, and add `GridView1.AllowPaging = true;' just after the end of the mentioned event.

Comment: so thanks mamnon  damet garm bazam iraniha khoshhal shodam ba shoma ashna shodam omidvaram shoma ro be list doostanam add kardam